# Returning a pointer to a device allocated matrix from C to Fortran

Tags: c, cuda, fortran, intel-fortran

First off, I'm kind of new with Fortran/C/CUDA. Secondly, I'm working on a Fortran/C program that performs matrix vector multiplication on the GPU using cuBLAS. I need to multiply multiple (up to 1000) vectors with the one matrix before I need to update the matrix contents. However, the current version I have has to reallocate the matrix every time a new vector is sent to the GPU (which is incredibly wasteful and slow since the matrix hasn't changed).

I want to be able to multiply the matrix with the vector without having to reallocate the matrix for every vector. An idea I had involved calling a separate C function that would allocate the matrix to the GPU, returns a pointer to the Fortran main program, and then calls another C function that performs the matrix vector multiplication.

Using ISO_C_BINDING, I returned a pointer to a floating point number into the variable:

```
type(C_PTR) :: ptr
```

and when I try to pass this into the matrix vector C function:

**in Fortran**

```
call cudaFunction(ptr,vector, N)
```

**in C**

```
extern "C" void cudaFunction_(float *mat, float *vector, int *N)
```

everything compiles and runs, but the execution of cublasSgemv fails to execute. Any ideas on why this would be happening? I've seen a few post kind of related but they never try to send the returned pointer back to C and this is where (I believe) I am having the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you not reinvent the wheel, but use the [cublas fortran bindings](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#appendix-b-cublas-fortran-bindings) that are provided for this purpose.

The "thunking" wrapper is not what you want.  It does implicit copy operations as needed, any time you use a cublas call in fortran.

You want the "non-thunking" wrapper, so you have explicit control over the copying going on.  You can use fortran equivalents of `Get/SetMatrix` and `Get/SetVector` to copy data back and forth.

There is a sample code (example B.2) showing how to use the non-thunking wrapper included in the cublas documentation.

Even if you do want to re-invent the wheel, the wrapper will show you how to make the necessary syntax work to move between C and Fortran.

On a standard linux CUDA install, the wrappers are in `/usr/local/cuda/src`
The non-thunking wrapper is `/usr/local/cuda/src/fortran.c`

Here's a fully worked example:

cublasf.f:

```
      program cublas_fortran_example
      implicit none
      integer i, j

c     helper functions
      integer cublas_init
      integer cublas_shutdown
      integer cublas_alloc
      integer cublas_free
      integer cublas_set_vector
      integer cublas_get_vector
c     selected blas functions
      double precision cublas_ddot
      external cublas_daxpy
      external cublas_dscal
      external cublas_dcopy
      double precision cublas_dnrm2
c     cublas variables
      integer cublas_status
      real*8 x(30), y(30)
      double precision alpha, beta
      double precision nrm
      integer*8 d_x, d_y, d_alpha, d_beta, d_nrm
      integer*8 dsize1, dlength1, dlength2
      double precision dresult



      write(*,*) "testing cublas fortran example"

c     initialize cublas library
c     CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS=0
      cublas_status = cublas_init()
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS Library initialization failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif
c     initialize data
      do j=1,30
        x(j) = 1.0
        y(j) = 2.0
      enddo
      dsize1 = 8
      dlength1 = 30
      dlength2 = 1
      alpha = 2.0
      beta = 3.0
c     allocate device storage
      cublas_status = cublas_alloc(dlength1, dsize1, d_x)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS device malloc failed"
         stop
      endif
      cublas_status = cublas_alloc(dlength1, dsize1, d_y)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS device malloc failed"
         stop
      endif
      cublas_status = cublas_alloc(dlength2, dsize1, d_alpha)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS device malloc failed"
         stop
      endif
      cublas_status = cublas_alloc(dlength2, dsize1, d_beta)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS device malloc failed"
         stop
      endif
      cublas_status = cublas_alloc(dlength2, dsize1, d_nrm)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS device malloc failed"
         stop
      endif

c     copy data from host to device

      cublas_status = cublas_set_vector(dlength1, dsize1, x, dlength2,
     >     d_x, dlength2)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS copy to device failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif
      cublas_status = cublas_set_vector(dlength1, dsize1, y, dlength2,
     >     d_y, dlength2)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS copy to device failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif

      dresult = cublas_ddot(dlength1, d_x, dlength2, d_y, dlength2)
      write(*,*) "dot product result=",dresult

      dresult = cublas_dnrm2(dlength1, d_x, dlength2)
      write(*,*) "nrm2 of x result=",dresult

      dresult = cublas_dnrm2(dlength1, d_y, dlength2)
      write(*,*) "nrm2 of y result=",dresult

      call cublas_daxpy(dlength1, alpha, d_x, dlength2, d_y, dlength2)
      cublas_status = cublas_get_vector(dlength1, dsize1, d_y, dlength2,
     >     y, dlength2)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS copy to host failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif
      write(*,*) "daxpy y(1)  =", y(1)
      write(*,*) "daxpy y(30) =", y(30)


      call cublas_dscal(dlength1, beta, d_x, dlength2)
      cublas_status = cublas_get_vector(dlength1, dsize1, d_x, dlength2,
     >     x, dlength2)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS copy to host failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif
      write(*,*) "dscal x(1)  =", x(1)
      write(*,*) "dscal x(30) =", x(30)


      call cublas_dcopy(dlength1, d_x, dlength2, d_y, dlength2)
      cublas_status = cublas_get_vector(dlength1, dsize1, d_y, dlength2,
     >     y, dlength2)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS copy to host failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif
      write(*,*) "dcopy y(1)  =", y(1)
      write(*,*) "dcopy y(30) =", y(30)

c     deallocate GPU memory and exit
      cublas_status = cublas_free(d_x)
      cublas_status = cublas_free(d_y)
      cublas_status = cublas_free(d_alpha)
      cublas_status = cublas_free(d_beta)
      cublas_status = cublas_free(d_nrm)
      cublas_status = cublas_shutdown()
      stop
      end
```

compile/run:

```
$ gfortran -c -o cublasf.o cublasf.f
$ gcc -c -DCUBLAS_GFORTRAN -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/src -o fortran.o /usr/local/cuda/src/fortran.c
$ gfortran -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcublas -o cublasf cublasf.o fortran.o
$ ./cublasf
 testing cublas fortran example
 dot product result=   60.0000000000000
 nrm2 of x result=   5.47722557505166
 nrm2 of y result=   10.9544511501033
 daxpy y(1)  =   4.00000000000000
 daxpy y(30) =   4.00000000000000
 dscal x(1)  =   3.00000000000000
 dscal x(30) =   3.00000000000000
 dcopy y(1)  =   3.00000000000000
 dcopy y(30) =   3.00000000000000
$
```

CUDA 5.0, RHEL 5.5

Comment: Thank you for the very quick and extremely helpful response. I just have a few follow up questions. 1) I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and need to use the Intel Fortran (ifort) compiler. When I run the code above, using gcc and gfortran, I get a variety of errors saying: 

fortran.o: In function 'cublas_init_':

fortran.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to 'cublasInit'

where are these arising from (I copy and pasted your example from above)? Also, is there a way to use this with ifort? I keep getting and undefined compiler error from fortran_common.h.

Comment: Which version of CUDA are you using?  Where are your cuda libraries installed?  It sounds like your link operation is not finding the cublas library.  For `ifort`, change the `-DCUBLAS_GFORTRAN` to `-DCUBLAS_INTEL_FORTRAN`  There may be other changes needed as well.  It's supposed to be usable with `ifort` but there may be some syntax changes needed.

Comment: I'm using Cuda 5.5 and they are installed in /usr/local/cuda-5.5/, which I changed accordingly in your above example. I'll try -DCUBLAS_INTEL_FORTRAN. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't have any trouble compiling exactly what I show in this answer on CUDA 5.5/RHEL 5.5  As far as I know, Ubuntu 13.10 is not an officially supported distro for any version of CUDA.

Comment: Sorry for the late response (I was on vacation for Spring Break). I tried to rerun your example code from above (word for word) and the output I receieved was this:

`fortran.o: In function `cublas_init_':
fortran.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `cublasInit'
fortran.o: In function `cublas_shutdown_':
fortran.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `cublasShutdown'
fortran.o: In function `cublas_alloc_':
fortran.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `cublasAlloc'
fortran.o: In function `cublas_free_':
fortran.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `cublasFree'
`

but for all the functions

Comment: Any idea on why I'm getting this error? Is it an Ubuntu issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The linker (gfortran) is not finding the cublas library.  You would need to change the `-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64` switch to point to the location of the cublas library on your machine.  There may be other issues as well, such as improperly formed symbolic links for libcublas.so. If you still can't figure it out, open a new question, and provide: 1. The exact compile and link commands you are issuing, 2. the actual location of the cuda install on your machine, 3. the exact and complete output and error messages, 4. the directory contents of the ...cuda/lib64 directory on your machine.

Comment: I was able to fix it! all I had to do was flip the final linking command a bit. Instead of: "gfortran -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcublas -o cublasf cublasf.o fortran.o" I used "gfortran -o cublasf cublasf.o fortran.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcublas" and it worked. 

Thank you again for your help, you have been a lifesaver!