# Undefined references to cublas functions using ifort (cuBLAS Fortran Bindings)

Tags: cuda, fortran, intel-fortran, cublas

I have a sample cuBLAS Fortran binding routine provided from a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390812/returning-a-pointer-to-a-device-allocated-matrix-from-c-to-fortran). I'm running Ubuntu 13.10, IFORT 14.0.1, and Cuda 5.5. The code is below:

**cublas.f**

```
      program cublas_fortran_example
      implicit none
      integer i, j

c     helper functions
      integer cublas_init
      integer cublas_shutdown
      integer cublas_alloc
      integer cublas_free
      integer cublas_set_vector
      integer cublas_get_vector
c     selected blas functions
      double precision cublas_ddot
      external cublas_daxpy
      external cublas_dscal
      external cublas_dcopy
      double precision cublas_dnrm2
c     cublas variables
      integer cublas_status
      real*8 x(30), y(30)
      double precision alpha, beta
      double precision nrm
      integer*8 d_x, d_y, d_alpha, d_beta, d_nrm
      integer*8 dsize1, dlength1, dlength2
      double precision dresult



      write(*,*) "testing cublas fortran example"

c     initialize cublas library
c     CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS=0
      cublas_status = cublas_init()
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS Library initialization failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif
c     initialize data
      do j=1,30
        x(j) = 1.0
        y(j) = 2.0
      enddo
      dsize1 = 8
      dlength1 = 30
      dlength2 = 1
      alpha = 2.0
      beta = 3.0
c     allocate device storage
      cublas_status = cublas_alloc(dlength1, dsize1, d_x)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS device malloc failed"
         stop
      endif
      cublas_status = cublas_alloc(dlength1, dsize1, d_y)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS device malloc failed"
         stop
      endif
      cublas_status = cublas_alloc(dlength2, dsize1, d_alpha)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS device malloc failed"
         stop
      endif
      cublas_status = cublas_alloc(dlength2, dsize1, d_beta)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS device malloc failed"
         stop
      endif
      cublas_status = cublas_alloc(dlength2, dsize1, d_nrm)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS device malloc failed"
         stop
      endif

c     copy data from host to device

      cublas_status = cublas_set_vector(dlength1, dsize1, x, dlength2,
     >     d_x, dlength2)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS copy to device failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif
      cublas_status = cublas_set_vector(dlength1, dsize1, y, dlength2,
     >     d_y, dlength2)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS copy to device failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif

      dresult = cublas_ddot(dlength1, d_x, dlength2, d_y, dlength2)
      write(*,*) "dot product result=",dresult

      dresult = cublas_dnrm2(dlength1, d_x, dlength2)
      write(*,*) "nrm2 of x result=",dresult

      dresult = cublas_dnrm2(dlength1, d_y, dlength2)
      write(*,*) "nrm2 of y result=",dresult

      call cublas_daxpy(dlength1, alpha, d_x, dlength2, d_y, dlength2)
      cublas_status = cublas_get_vector(dlength1, dsize1, d_y, dlength2,
     >     y, dlength2)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS copy to host failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif
      write(*,*) "daxpy y(1)  =", y(1)
      write(*,*) "daxpy y(30) =", y(30)


      call cublas_dscal(dlength1, beta, d_x, dlength2)
      cublas_status = cublas_get_vector(dlength1, dsize1, d_x, dlength2,
     >     x, dlength2)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS copy to host failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif
      write(*,*) "dscal x(1)  =", x(1)
      write(*,*) "dscal x(30) =", x(30)


      call cublas_dcopy(dlength1, d_x, dlength2, d_y, dlength2)
      cublas_status = cublas_get_vector(dlength1, dsize1, d_y, dlength2,
     >     y, dlength2)
      if (cublas_status /= 0) then
         write(*,*) "CUBLAS copy to host failed"
         write(*,*) "cublas_status=",cublas_status
         stop
      endif
      write(*,*) "dcopy y(1)  =", y(1)
      write(*,*) "dcopy y(30) =", y(30)

c     deallocate GPU memory and exit
      cublas_status = cublas_free(d_x)
      cublas_status = cublas_free(d_y)
      cublas_status = cublas_free(d_alpha)
      cublas_status = cublas_free(d_beta)
      cublas_status = cublas_free(d_nrm)
      cublas_status = cublas_shutdown()
      stop
      end
```

When I compile using gfortran, I get the correct output as show below:

**compile and run**

```
$gfortran -c -o cublasf.o cublasf.f
$nvcc -c -DCUBLAS_GFORTRAN -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/src -o fortran.o /usr/local/cuda/src/fortran.c
$gfortran -o cublasf cublasf.o fortran.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcublas
$ ./cublasf 
 testing cublas fortran example
 dot product result=   60.000000000000000     
 nrm2 of x result=   5.4772255750516612     
 nrm2 of y result=   10.954451150103322     
 daxpy y(1)  =   4.0000000000000000     
 daxpy y(30) =   4.0000000000000000     
 dscal x(1)  =   3.0000000000000000     
 dscal x(30) =   3.0000000000000000     
 dcopy y(1)  =   3.0000000000000000     
 dcopy y(30) =   3.0000000000000000
```

However, I need to use the Intel Fortran compiler with the cuBLAS library, but when I switch from gfortran to ifort, I get a variety of undefined references, as show below:

```
$ifort -c -o cublasf.o cublasf.f
$nvcc -c -DCUBLAS_INTEL_FORTRAN -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/src -o fortran.o /usr/local/cuda/src/fortran.c
$ifort -o cublasf cublasf.o fortran.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcublas
cublasf.o: In function `MAIN__':
cublasf.f:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `cublas_init_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x1f5): undefined reference to `cublas_alloc_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x21c): undefined reference to `cublas_alloc_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x243): undefined reference to `cublas_alloc_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x26a): undefined reference to `cublas_alloc_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x291): undefined reference to `cublas_alloc_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to `cublas_set_vector_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x3d1): undefined reference to `cublas_set_vector_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x4d5): undefined reference to `cublas_ddot_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x56f): undefined reference to `cublas_dnrm2_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x609): undefined reference to `cublas_dnrm2_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x6b6): undefined reference to `cublas_daxpy_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x6e6): undefined reference to `cublas_get_vector_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x8c5): undefined reference to `cublas_dscal_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0x8f5): undefined reference to `cublas_get_vector_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0xad7): undefined reference to `cublas_dcopy_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0xb07): undefined reference to `cublas_get_vector_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0xcce): undefined reference to `cublas_free_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0xcdd): undefined reference to `cublas_free_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0xcec): undefined reference to `cublas_free_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0xcfb): undefined reference to `cublas_free_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0xd0a): undefined reference to `cublas_free_'
cublasf.f:(.text+0xd11): undefined reference to `cublas_shutdown_'
```

I've seen some other posts regarding this same issue but with no real solution/explanation. If anyone could explain why these references are undefined when using ifort and not when using gfortran, along with any solutions to fixing the issue, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The important point to notice is the appended `_` on the end of the symbols in the ifort emitted code. There is probably a way to control symbol mangling in ifort. I don't know off hand what that is. Otherwise you might need to use the ISO_C_BINDING mechanism

Comment: By default on Linux `ifort` uses a single underscore (`-assume underscore` -- please read the man page for details. How about putting the libs first? As in `ifort -o cublasf -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcublas cublasf.o fortran.o `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intel Fortran documentation states, that](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/464094)

> On Linux and OS X systems, the compiler appends an underscore
>   character to external user-defined names.

You need to disable it by

```
ifort -assume nounderscore ...
```

Alse consider [names](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/464108) case

> This is the default on Linux* and OS X* systems. The compiler ignores case differences in identifiers and converts external names to lowercase.

So you would maybe need also

```
-names uppercase
```

Comment: I tried using `ifort -assme nounderscore ...` and I got the same error as above but without an underscore at the end of the function call. If it's any help, I'm trying to access the function wrappers in `/usr/local/cuda/src/fortran_common.h`. It seems to contain the function wrappers I need under `#elif defined(CUBLAS_INTEL_FORTRAN)` tag, however it seems to be accessing the wrappers underneath the `#if defined(CUBLAS_GFORTRAN) || defined(CUBLAS_G95)` by the output I'm getting. Thank you

Comment: what give you nm -D /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so | grep "cublas_init" ?

Comment: I got nothing when I ran it

Comment: is cublas_init defined in /usr/local/cuda/src/fortran.c?

Comment: Yes it is. `int CUBLAS_INIT (void)
{
    return (int)cublasInit ();
}
`

Comment: When I run  `nm -D /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so | grep "cublasInit"`. 

I get `000000000001e590 T cublasInit`

Comment: nm fortran.o | grep -i "cublas_init" ?

Comment: the output I get is `0000000000000000 T CUBLAS_INIT`

Comment: when you switch order to ifort ... fortran.o cublasf.o ... ?

Comment: Still getting the same error as above (by the way, thanks for the time your putting in to help me with this, I really appreciate it)

Comment: Thank you!! Adding '-names uppercase' fixed my issue.

Comment: np; Maybe you can remove some code from cublas.f presented here, so it would be easier to read the question in the future (maybe just remove everything after `cublas_status = cublas_init()` line and some initializations before)