# cublas direct fortran c-binding using cublas.lib

Tags: cuda, fortran, cublas

I'm attempting to set up an interface to use cublas.lib in fortran without any separate c-code.  I have seen a few examples of this and tried to duplicate those but I having trouble.

Both of these examples work for me (cudart and cusolver)

[Find available graphics card memory using Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507169/find-available-graphics-card-memory-using-fortran/27576218#27576218)

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/using-cusolverdn-in-fortran-code/39732/5

I have an additional include directory of C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2\lib\x64 and additional dependencies of  cublas.lib cusolver.lib cudart.lib.  Everything compiles fine (As I was able to run the examples above.

When I run the code below cublasCreate returns 7 (CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE)

```
!==================================================================
!Interface to cusolverDn and CUDA C functions
!==================================================================
! C binding
!     https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html
!
! Similar CUDA examples
!     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507169/find-available-graphics-card-memory-using-fortran%5B/url%5D
!     https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/using-cusolverdn-in-fortran-code/39732/5
!     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390812/returning-a-pointer-to-a-device-allocated-matrix-from-c-to-fortran
!     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150748/mixed-language-cuda-programming

module cudaThings

interface

    ! cudaMalloc
    integer (c_int) function cudaMalloc ( buffer, size ) bind (C, name="cudaMalloc" ) 
        use iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        type (c_ptr)  :: buffer
        integer (c_size_t), value :: size
    end function cudaMalloc
    
    ! cudaMemcpy 
    ! A_mem_stat = cudaMemcpy(gpuPtr,cpuPtr,sizeof(ptr),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
    !     note: cudaMemcpyHostToDevice = 1
    !     note: cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost = 2
    integer (c_int) function cudaMemcpy ( dst, src, count, kind ) bind (C, name="cudaMemcpy" )
        use iso_c_binding
        type (C_PTR), value :: dst, src
        integer (c_size_t), value :: count, kind
    end function cudaMemcpy
    
    ! cudaFree
    integer (c_int) function cudaFree(buffer)  bind(C, name="cudaFree")
        use iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        type (C_PTR), value :: buffer
    end function cudaFree
    
    ! get memory info
    integer (c_int) function cudaMemGetInfo(fre, tot) bind(C, name="cudaMemGetInfo")
        use iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        type(c_ptr),value :: fre
        type(c_ptr),value :: tot
    end function cudaMemGetInfo


     integer(c_int) function cusolverDnCreate(cusolver_Hndl) bind(C,name="cusolverDnCreate")
       use iso_c_binding
       implicit none
     
       type(c_ptr)::cusolver_Hndl
     end function
     
     integer(c_int) function cusolverDnDestroy(cusolver_Hndl) bind(C,name="cusolverDnDestroy")
       use iso_c_binding
       implicit none
     
       type(c_ptr),value::cusolver_Hndl
     end function
     
     integer(c_int) function cublasCreate(cublas_Hndl) bind(C,name="cublasCreate_v2")
        use iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        
        type(c_ptr),value::cublas_Hndl
     end function
     
    integer(c_int) function cublasDestroy(cublas_Hndl) bind(C,name="cublasDestroy_v2")
      use iso_c_binding
      implicit none
     
      type(c_ptr),value::cublas_Hndl
    end function
end interface  
  
end module 

program cudaTest
  use iso_c_binding
  use cudaThings
  implicit none
  
  ! GPU stuff
  type(c_ptr) :: cublas_Hndl
  integer*4    :: cublas_stat
  
  ! get handle
  cublas_stat = cublasCreate(cublas_Hndl) 
  write(*,*) cublas_stat
  if (cublas_stat .ne. 0 ) then
     write (*, '(A, I2)') " cublasCreate error: ", cublas_stat
     stop
  end if
end program
```

I'm on windows 10, intel fortran, cuda 12.2, with a 930M graphics card.

Comment: Your use of cublas_Hndl as a pointer is wrong. The use of a pointer  in cublasCreate is the C pass by reference idiom

Comment: Hmm I'm not quite following.  Isn't the cublas_Hndl a c_ptr and being passed by reference within the interface that I made?  If I swap for cusolverDnCreate it works fine

Comment: You are passing an uninitialised pointer to the API. That won’t work

Comment: Doesn't cublasCreate initialize the pointer?  What is the difference between cusolverDnCreate (works) and cublasCreate (doesn't work)?  Function signatures in my code on the CUDA API for both look identical to me.

Comment: Ok removing value from my interface makes it work `type(c_ptr) ::cublas_Hndl`.  Still confused why its different for cublasCreate vs cusolveDnCreate

Comment: Edit:  Its not different.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is going on, it is worth analyzing how the underlying C code works before writing an interface to it.

In C, the correct canonical call looks like this:

```
cublasHandle_t handle;
cublasStatus_t status = cublasCreate(&handle);
```

which is passing idiomatically the `cublasHandle_t` (itself a pointer to an opaque structure)  by reference (even though C doesn't have explicit pass by reference semantics).

If you did this:

```
cublasHandle_t *handle;
cublasStatus_t status = cublasCreate(handle);
```

you are passing an uninitialized pointer to the routine, which should result in a failure. I haven't done much work with F2003 stype C interop, but to my eyes this:

```
  type(c_ptr) :: cublas_Hndl
  integer*4    :: cublas_stat
  
  ! get handle
  cublas_stat = cublasCreate(cublas_Hndl)
```

is the same as the theoretically non-working C version, whereas this:

```
  type(c_ptr) :: cublas_Hndl
  integer*4    :: cublas_stat
  
  ! get handle
  cublas_stat = cublasCreate(c_loc(cublas_Hndl))
```

would be like the first working C version and more likely to work correctly.